# Django: Add response header when using render or render_to_response

Tags: django, httpresponse

How do I add a response header to a Django response? I have:

```
response = HttpResponse()
response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'

return render(request, "template.html", {}) 

# Alternately using render_to_response
# return render_to_response("template.html", {})
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Assign the result of `render` to a variable, set the header, then return the response.

```
response = render(request, "template.html", {})
response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
return response
```

Most of the time, it is simpler to user `render` than `render_to_response`. However, if you are using `render_to_response`, the same approach will work:

```
response = render_to_response("template.html", {})
response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
return response
```